# Print from Linux without drivers trough CUPS

Tags: networking, printing, samba, cups

**What I am trying to do:**
To print from any computer in my network, regardless of drivers.

**What I have:**
3 printers
An ubuntu print server with CUPS and all printers working well on it
A network :)

**The problem:**
The server is 32bits which is good because I've got drivers for all my printers in such architecture, My everyday's computer is a 64 bits, and I haven't found drivers for one of the printers (the best).
¿How can I print from my everyday's computer?

Comment: In my eyes the most important fact is the OS running on your client. Please tell us more than 32/64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, the printer is a Xerox phaser 6000B and the client is a Gnome Ubuntu 15.04 x64

Comment: So all your clients are linux? No windows? In that case you need not use a special 64bit driver - your printer understands postscript.

Comment: Some are windows 8 32bits, so they have no problems. The postscript understanding is a question? If yes, how can I know it?